# Make Multiple sparkLine bar chart

Tags: javascript

I want to make a multiple bar chart according to the response. Here i want to make 4 chart but only one graph is displayed in the app. But the loops run four times and only single graph is seen.Can anyone tell me why this graph is obtained single time? The below is my code. The console prints the value from 0 to 4 but graph is seen only one.For reference only 4 is given. The totalCount is dynamic one.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>jQuery Shield UI Demos</title>
    <link id="themecss" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
          href="//www.shieldui.com/shared/components/latest/css/light/all.min.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//www.shieldui.com/shared/components/latest/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//www.shieldui.com/shared/components/latest/js/shieldui-all.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body class="theme-light">

<div class="test">
    <div style="width: 270px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; height: 100px;" id="sparkLine"></div>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        //find the tota number of categories from the repons
        var totalCount = 4;
        var categoryName = ["Asthama","HTB","Cold","diarrohea"]
        for(i=0;i<= totalCount;i++){
            console.log("I am called"+i+"times")
        $("#sparkLine").append().shieldChart({
            theme: "light",
            chartAreaPaddingTop: -7,
            chartLegend: {
                enabled: true,
                title:categoryName[i]
            },
            seriesSettings: {
                bar: {
                    activeSettings: {
                        pointHoveredState: {
                            enabled: false
                        }
                    },
                    pointMark: {
                        enabled: false
                    }
                }
            },
            axisX: {
                axisTickText: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                plotStripWidth: 0,
                drawWidth: 0,
                ticksWidth: 0,
                ticksHeight: 0
            },
            axisY: {
                axisTickText: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                plotStripWidth: 0,
                drawWidth: 0,
                ticksWidth: 0
            },
            dataSeries: [{
                seriesType: "bar",
                data: [2000, 2100, 1900, 1700, 1000, 500, 700, 120, 4000, 3100, 3200, 3700, 300, 200, 700, 900, 1700, 700, 800]
            }]
        });
    };
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

For different map, you need to use different id.

```
 $("#sparkLine"+i).append().shieldChart({
```

html dynamically added in js

```
for(i=0;i< totalCount;i++){
            finalOutput = finalOutput +  '<div style="width: 270px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; height: 100px;" id="sparkLine'+ i +'"></div>';
            document.getElementById("graph123").innerHTML = finalOutput;
}
```

check this link [fiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/9mvwjbru/)

Comment: That 4 is not static value and can be any number.Just for reference i have provided 4.

Comment: is it fine or u want any tunes? @jennysam